# Different container heights

Tags: css, joomla

I have several pages on my website and the containers in which the content is placed differ from each other in height. I set in a min-height because some pages aren't that big and I don't want them to be very short. But now the other pages also stop at that min-height. I just want the container to be as long as the code requires but with a min-height of e.g. 650px. Here's the code:

```css
#container {  margin: 0 auto;  padding: 0 0 20px 0;  text-align: left;  width: 1024px;  min-height: 650px;  overflow: hidden;  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.92);}
```

Since it's in Joomla, I don't have a general code for all pages but the pages are built up like this:

```
<div id="container> <div id="content"> </div></div>
```

It is built with Joomla, before I hadn't have any problems with just HTML. They are all linked to 'template.css'.

Here is the link to the website, maybe that'll help:

http://www.joomla.sklebekeaalst.be/kalender

As you can see, the calender is cut short and needs to be longer.

Comment: You should post some example code here in the question that demonstrates the issue. Otherwise, the question will no longer match the website it points to if the website ever changes. And it will! Anyway, the problem is with the `float:left` on the `#content`. The container doesn't know how high its contents are.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you only set the min-height and not the height as well. If min-height is set without height, height computes to auto and may start to do really weird things depending on its containing element and positioning. Plus, if the auto height is less than the min-height, the min-height will always be rendered. Set a height property such as `height: 100% ;` on both the element and the containing div and that will likely fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

to have sibling elements with same height just add display:flex in the parent container CSS of those sibling elements

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to make a div for the content in the article and then put a float:left on it. Everything is fine now.